# Cant find base path for bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm using Symfony2 and want to generate getters and setters for the entities by running:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities TestBundle
```

[image]

The Console returns me the following message:

> [RuntimeException] Can't find base path for "TestBundle" (path: "C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectX\src\Namespace\TestBundle", destination: "C:/xampp/htdocs/ProjectX/src/Namespace/TestBundle").

The Bundle exists at this location: `C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectX\src\Namespace\TestBundle`

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Just to add something else in case others reach this. I had an issue causing the same error but it was due to my entities living in a codebase that used PSR-4. Doctrine does not support PSR-4 when doing anything with code generation. It has to do with how they map class namespaces to filesystem paths and how PSR-4 allows class/namespace paths that don't directly map to the filesystem.

https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282

Answer (score 2):

I had this probleme caused by some issue with lower case /upper case in my bundle directory. It souldn't be an issue under windows, but the php function str_replace is case sensitive an generate the error

```
//Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\MetadataFactory

private function getBasePathForClass($name, $namespace, $path)
    {
        $namespace = str_replace('\\', '/', $namespace);
        $search = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
        $destination = str_replace('/' . $namespace, '', $search, $c);

        if ($c != 1) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Can\'t find base path for "%s" (path: "%s", destination: "%s").', $name, $path, $destination));
        }

        return $destination;
    }
```

Doctrine can't re-create the class path based on the namespace : So it means your namespace or your folder is wrong (check case)

Answer (score 0):

Name of your Bundle php file is wrong
change from **TestBundle.php** to **NamespaceTestBundle.php** in path: **C:/xampp/htdocs/ProjectX/src/Namespace/TestBundle/**

Comment: After a rename occurs this error: 'Fatal error: Class 'Namespace\TestBundle\TestBundle' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectX\app\AppKernel.php on line 21'

Comment: @David if you're new to Symfony2 you're better of removing and regenerating the bundle rather than hunting down invalid namespaces

Answer (score 0):

[John Pancoast's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404931/john-pancoast) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783993/cant-find-base-path-for-bundle#answer-25882485) is correct.

> Just to add something else in case others reach this. I had an issue causing the same error but it was due to my entities living in a codebase that used PSR-4. Doctrine does not support PSR-4 when doing anything with code generation. It has to do with how they map class namespaces to filesystem paths and how PSR-4 allows class/namespace paths that don't directly map to the filesystem.
>
> https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282

To clarify exactly what is needed to resolve the error message; edit your bundle's `composer.json` file, and also change the bundle's folder structure.

in `composer.json` change `psr-4` to `psr-0`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Acme\\Bundle\\AwesomeBundle\\": "" }
},
```

to:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Acme\\Bundle\\AwesomeBundle\\": "" }
},
```

Change bundle's folder structure from:

```
vendor
 +--acme
     +--awsome-bundle
         |--Controller
         |--Entity
```

to:

```
vendor
 +--acme
     +--awsome-bundle
         +--Acme
             +--Bundle
                 +--AwsomeBundle
                     |--Controller
                     |--Entity
```

The following command wil no longer throw an exception:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AwesomeBundle
```