# Symfony3 error Namespace does not contain any mapped entities

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I tried generate getters and setters in Symfony 3.0.1

when i run command

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities VendorName/MyBundle/EntityName
```

i have error

```
Namespace "VendorName\MyBundle\EntityName" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

**where is the mistake?**

**Edit-1:** First generate entity with YAML format

**Edit-2:** I tried generate getters and setters for vendor bundle

Also i try with command **php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities VendorNameMyBundle:EntityName** and have another error:

```
Can't find base path for "VendorName\MyBundle\Entity\EntityName" (path: "/home/site/vendor/vendorname/mybundle/Entity", destination: "/home/site/vendor/vendorname/mybundle/Entity").
```

Comment: did you first generate an entity classes with annotation mappings? (or YAML, XML mapping, whatever). Here the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

Comment: First generate entity with YAML format

Comment: what's the path of your entity class? `MyBundle\Entity\EntityName`? Is `VendorNameMyBundle` a valid and registered bundle name?

Comment: VendorNameMyBundle is a valid and registered bundle name

Comment: Where is your EntityName.php file saved? What is your namespace value in EntityName.php? What is the class name in EntityName.php?

Answer (score 2):

As [John Pancoast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404931/john-pancoast) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783993/cant-find-base-path-for-bundle#answer-25882485) to a different question:

> Doctrine does not support PSR-4 when doing anything with code generation. It has to do with how they map class namespaces to filesystem paths and how PSR-4 allows class/namespace paths that don't directly map to the filesystem.
>
> https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/282

To clarify what exactly is needed to resolve the error message; You have to edit your bundle's `composer.json` file, and also change the bundle's folder structure.

in `composer.json` change `psr-4` to `psr-0`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Acme\\Bundle\\AwesomeBundle\\": "" }
},
```

to:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "Acme\\Bundle\\AwesomeBundle\\": "" }
},
```

Change bundle's folder structure from:

```
vendor
 +--acme
     +--awesome-bundle
         |--Controller
         |--Entity
```

to:

```
vendor
 +--acme
     +--awesome-bundle
         +--Acme
             +--Bundle
                 +--AwesomeBundle
                     |--Controller
                     |--Entity
```

The following command will no longer throw an exception:

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AwesomeBundle
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in command, you trying to generate entities but you provide class name for one entity. Try the following for all entities:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities VendorName/MyBundle
```

or if you want just one entity:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity VendorName/MyBundle/EntityName
```

Answer (score -1):

**Symfony 3.22 with src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php**

if you add new field using ORM

```
**/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_login", type="datetimetz")
 */
private $lastLogin;**
```

just use

**use php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle**

it will check all your Entities r and update getters and setters

then use

**php bin/console doctrine:schema:update** to update your database

use

**php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force** in PROD enviroment

Comment: upvote for this "use php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle" i always specify the entity, but it's way easier to just point to a bundle.